# How can I manually create tuples and bags in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to make my own tuples and bags rather than loading from files, to experiment with things, how can I do this?

I would like to do something like:

```
>> a = {1, 2, 3} as (i: int)
>> describe a;
a: {i: int}
>> dump a;
(1)
(2)
(3)
>> b = a
>> c = cross a, b;
>> describe c;
c: {a::i: int, b::i: int}
>> dump c;
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,1)
(2,2)
(2,3)
(3,1)
(3,2)
(3,3)
```

Hopefully the spirit of what I want to do is captured, and if there is some other way of doing things that I'm not aware of, that can be the answer.  Or some reasoning can be provided so that I can believe that there is no way to do this so I can give up trying.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as Pig simply creates map reduce jobs from the provided instructions. In so far it needs to operate on input data available to a map reduce job. The grunt shell is misleading because it will only run the Pig frontend which checks basic syntax until it encounters a store or dump statement, which will then trigger generation of map reduce and execution. I've found the easiest solution is to generate small CSV files as basis for experimentation.

Comment: You can read dummy input file and reassign the actual values that you want.

e.g. a = load 'foobar' using AvroStorage();
b = foreach a generate 10 as x, 20 as y;
c = d;
e = c cross d;
and so on.